# website blocked by netgear firewall

Tags: networking, google-chrome, firewall

I have a Netgear DGN10000 supplied by Virgin Media in the UK. It is running the latest firmware (V2.1.00.25_VG). For some reason it appears to be blocking all URLs which contain "microsoft.com" but........only in chrome. In IE, it works fine.

I've attached the router config as well.

Any ideas why it could be blocked?

Update: The error message only occurs on my computer's Chrome. On all other computers in the network microsoft.com works fine. I don't have any extensions installed.

[image: blocked in chrome]
[image: working in IE]
[image: router config]

Answer (score -1):

In my case, it was a cookie. Cleared Chrome's cookies and microsoft.com started working.